# animation-list with 510 images causes OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, android-animation

I have been provided with exactly 510 images(Lets call them animation0000 through animation0510) and wish to create an animated imageview that loops through all of these images continuously.

I used the animation-list as proposed but am now getting the following exception when trying to start the application.

> 01-20 18:20:49.024: E/AndroidRuntime(24340): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   01-20 18:20:49.024: E/AndroidRuntime(24340):
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError 01-20 18:20:49.024:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24340):  at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method) 01-20
>   18:20:49.024: E/AndroidRuntime(24340):    at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
>   01-20 18:20:49.024: E/AndroidRuntime(24340):  at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
>   01-20 18:20:49.024: E/AndroidRuntime(24340):  at
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
>   01-20 18:20:49.024: E/AndroidRuntime(24340):  at
>   android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1992) 01-20
>   18:20:49.024: E/AndroidRuntime(24340):    at
>   android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:660) 01-20
>   18:20:49.024: E/AndroidRuntime(24340):    at
>   android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:282)
>   01-20 18:20:49.024: E/AndroidRuntime(24340):  at
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:885)
>   01-20 18:20:49.024: E/AndroidRuntime(24340):  at
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:822)

Each item in the animation-list looks like this :

```
    <item
    android:drawable="@drawable/z_animation0123"
    android:duration="20"/>
```

and the ImageView was included like this :

```
<ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/zzz_animation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/baby_logo_animation"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />
```

The animation is started in onActivity like this :

```
    // Start zzz animation
    ImageView zImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.zzz_animation_view);
    zImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.z_complete_animation);

    AnimationDrawable zAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) zImageView.getBackground();
    zAnimation.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create [an `<animation-list>` drawable resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Frame) pointing to those 510 images and how long each should be on the screen. Use `android:oneshot="false"` on the `<animation-list>` element to have it loop. That resulting resource can then be used with an `ImageView` widget.

Comment: Whie Im grateful for your help you wouldn't happen to know of a "fast" method of including 510 items in this animation list?

Comment: @litemode: Write a script to generate the file.

Comment: I tried doing this and the result was an exception when trying to start the application, see my edit for specifics.

Comment: @litemode: Your 510 images, combined, represent more RAM than you have room for. Either reduce the image count or reduce the image size.